# Difference between osrm nearest and osrm match services

Tags: python, python-requests, gis, openstreetmap, osrm

I want to match gps coordinates to osm nodes. The osrm document clearly states that match service is for that purpose. But I see most of them using nearest service for that purpose. Why so? Also any examples of Match service and what is the main difference between the two service for the matching operation.Which one is better?

Answer (score 0):

As per the [OSRM API Documentation](http://project-osrm.org/docs/v5.5.1/api/#match-service),

1. the `neareast` service a query endpoint where the nearest `number` of `waypoint` objects to the snapped `coordinates` (single coordinate allowed) are returned.

   ```
    GET http://{server}/nearest/v1/{profile}/{coordinates}.json?number={number}
   ```
2. On the other hand, as the name suggests `match` service does something quite different and as one can say more complex. It accepts multiple `coordinates` and matches these points in a plausible way to the route network. As it can be seen from the dummy and a bit manipulated response; `matchings` array defines the `confidence` (calculated by OSRM), `geometry` (provided in arguments), `legs` (defines the route details `annotations` and `overview` arguments provide flexibility) and `tracepoints` array that lists the `waypoints` with additional properties.

   ```
    GET /match/v1/{profile}/{coordinates}?steps={true|false}&geometries={polyline|polyline6|geojson}&overview={simplified|full|false}&annotations={true|false}
   ```

- `coordinates`: comma separated GPS points
- `steps`: route steps for each route
- `geometries`: 3 formats are supported for route geometry.
- `overview`: adds the overview geometry according to the given value.
- `annotations`: returns additional metadata for each coordinate.

Dummy `Match` service response overview as it is not very clearly provided:

```json
{
    "code": "Ok",
    "matchings": [
        {
            "confidence": 0.980739,
            "geometry": {
                "coordinates": [
                    # coordinates here
                ],
                "type": "LineString"
            },
            "legs": [
                {
                    "annotation": {
                        # optional 
                    },
                    "steps": [
                        {
                            "intersections": [
                                {
                                    "out": 0,
                                    "entry": [
                                        true
                                    ],
                                    "bearings": [
                                        12
                                    ],
                                    "location": [
                                        28.98672,
                                        41.041189
                                    ]
                                }
                            ],
                            "driving_side": "right",
                            "geometry": {
                                "coordinates": [
                                    # coordinates here
                                ],
                                "type": "LineString"
                            },
                            "mode": "driving",
                            "duration": 95.6,
                            "maneuver": {
                            },
                            "weight": 95.6,
                            "distance": 796.3,
                            "name": "Cumhuriyet Caddesi"
                        },
                    ],
                    "distance": 1250.9,
                    "duration": 150.2,
                    "summary": "Cumhuriyet Caddesi, Halaskargazi Caddesi",
                    "weight": 150.2
                }
            ],
            "distance": 1250.9,
            "duration": 150.2,
            "weight_name": "routability",
            "weight": 150.2
        }
    ],
    "tracepoints": [
        {
            # waypoint object with additional fields
        }
    ]
}
```